# Effect of spectral radius in dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the two quantities:

$$x^Tx \quad \& \quad x^TAx$$.

It is given that spectral radius of $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is less than 1 i.e., maximum magnitude of the eigen value of $A$ is less than 1. Which of the above quantites is greater?

I know that spectral radius less than $1$ implies in some $p$ operator norm $||Ax||_p < ||x||$, but it seems here we are specifically dealing with $p=2$, so can we still write some inequality relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general inequality that holds without further conditions on $A$.

If $A$ is normal (i.e. satisfies $A^TA = AA^T$), then it must hold that $|x^TAx| \leq \rho(A)x^Tx < x^Tx$. On the other hand, it is possible that there exists vectors $x$ that do not satisfy this condition more generally. For instance, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 10\\0 & 0},
$$
which has spectral radius $0$. The vector $x = (1,1)$ satisfies $x^TAx = 10$ but $x^Tx = 2$.

The fact that $\rho(A) < 1$ tells us that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we must have
$$
|x^TAx| = |x^T(\lambda x)| = |\lambda|\cdot x^Tx \leq \rho(A) \cdot x^Tx < x^Tx.
$$
However, as established with my counterexample, this inequality will not hold more generally.